# CPU Cooling fan trouble on Notebook

Tags: cpu, cooling, temperature

I'm using lenovo IdeaPad Z370

I just cleaned my fan and replaced thermal paste but the temperature still heating.

based on Psensors the temp very high:

[image]

I checked the fan again, I keep the back cover opened and turn on the laptop, I see the fan is not working! I don't know why, before this happened my fan keep running for a long time with noisy sound, after  I cleaned it then the fan didn't noisy anymore. I thought it was fine but my laptop keep heating and even worse.

Comment: Is the fan plugged in and getting power?

Comment: yes it plugged in, and I'm sure the cables ok.

Answer (score 0):

If your fan was running for a long time noisy, it was probably failing. The fact that you replaced the paste may have nothing to do with it stopping. It sounds like you need to replace it to me.